# print an image and text to receipt using cpcl in android MZ320 using Android

Tags: java, android, zebra-printers

I tried to print image and text in receipt using Cpcl format like that template. I have an example set logo as a variable and use function to read the image as string but that image in example is CPCL format I tried a lot  to get my logo as a cpcl format but i can't so I need to know how to get my image logo as cpcl format or another way to set image and text like that templete.

====================================================

[press here to see the image, this image have the ticket printed from worked example and that is what i need exactly but i can't change image to new one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgdZs.jpg)

```
//this template used to design my ticket which it has image and text in the same ticket like what i need.

    ! 0 200 200 1050 1

    PW 575

    TONE 0

    SPEED 3

    ON-FEED IGNORE

    NO-PACE

    BAR-SENSE

    BT 0 4 6

    B 128 3 30 120 20 0 ${barcode}

     /* the line below is used to set image as a string variable initialized
     in code from image i have in the worked example which its extension
    logo.cpcl" I don't know how it comes? and i need to change new logo to 
    Cpcl from png too "newlogo.png -> newlogo.cpcl" "pcx" x, y, data"*/

    PCX 420 790 ${Logo}

    ML 32

    T270 7 0 550 170 ${typeTicket}

    ENDML

    ML 32

    T270 7 0 498 170 ${validPeriod}

    ENDML

    ML 25

    T270 7 0 446 170 ${park}

    ENDML

    ML 32

    T270 7 0 370 170 ${price}

    ENDML

    ML 25

    T270 7 0 300 170 ${termsOfUse}

    ENDML





    PRINT
```

=================================

//this function only to understand what i use to read the image.

```
[//this line I use to call the function to read cpcl image!
//and here we got the image from resources

result = StringUtils.replace(result, "${Logo}", PrinterUtil.readFormat(context, R.raw.logo));


//this is the code used to read image as a string and it works perfectly with the example.

public static String readFormat(Context context, int formatRes) {

  InputStream is = null;

   try {

  is = context.getResources().openRawResource(formatRes);

   try {

   return readString(is);

  } catch (IOException e) {

   return null;

  }

  } finally {

   if (is != null) {

   try {

  is.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {

  }

  }

  }

}][1]
```

Comment: It's highly advisable that your question be formatted, as it is difficult to understand the relevant sections.

Comment: ok i will reformat every section with description@soufrk

Comment: @soufrk is it understandable now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a lot of solution but it doesn't  work too.
I have old code use image as aلاfile in cpcl extention instead of png or jpg I don't know how it comes?
but I created new solution when i searched in documentation i found that command and i did it using the blow steps.

How to change logo in Ticket using CPCL in  Android app?

1.You have to follow these steps to change it and make it work with **Zebra printer MZ320 & iMZ320**:

- At the first you have to change your image to black & white image using this link. https://pinetools.com/threshold-image.
- After that you have to get it as binary text from its pixels and resize it using custom width =120 using this link https://www.dcode.fr/binary-image.
- Copy binary text that you exported from image and paste it into text editor like notebad++.

2.Change all **(1)** ones in the image to **(F)** capital letter.

3.**your_ticket.cpcl** Then you have to use this command into it

```
`EXPANDED-GRAPHICS [ByteWidth] [Height] [X] [Y] [Data]<CR><LF>`.
```

4.ByteWidth is size of bytes of first line in your data like that example below.

5.Height is the number of lines in your data

6.Data is the image data copy it from text editor and write it like that example.

7.Example:

**EXPANDED-GRAPHICS 10 6 30 30** 
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

FF0000FFFFFFF00000FF

FF00000FFFFF000000FF

FF000000FFF0000000FF

FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

- Test your image data and print ticket if you find that your image not clear try to rotate it 35 degree to right like that image.